# Body should be in center while zoom in and zoom out of web page in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

How can the body be centered when zooming in & out a web page?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

body {
        font-family: 'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;
        margin:0px;
        font-weight: normal 300;
        font-size:14px;
        color:#595959;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: Use `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: not working @hulkinBrain

Comment: if you want to center something inside the body, you have to add the `margin: 0 auto;` to that element instead of the body then it'll work, i'm adding a snippet, take a look at that

Comment: I mean to say when im zoom in and out a page, its not coming in the center.. if you zoom out this page, all the content comes in center. But my page is not coming. @hulkinBrain please help me out

Comment: Could you please update your question by including your html code @Zaa Ra ? Another suggestion, remove `text-align: center;` css property from your body's css and add a div after `<body>` , put all your code (all the code before `</body>`) into the div which you just created. Then add `margin: 0 auto;` property to that div, See my answer, i've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the centering of the red color div when i added `margin: 0 auto;` to that div. Try zooming, it'll stay at the center only. You don't need `text-align: center` inside the body's css properties. Just add `margin: 0 auto;` to the div which you want to center *(i'm assuming you want the elements to be centered horizontally)*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = 'justCreatedThisDiv' style = 'margin: 0 auto;'>
        <!-- put all your code here -->
 <div style = "width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; margin: 0 auto;"></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```